# Prove $n$ is prime with some examples.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that a positive integer $n$ is prime, if no prime $p$ less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$.

Comment: What did you do to solve it?

Comment: @ZelosMalum I didn't solved it yet.

Comment: Evidently but what have you done AT ALL to try solving it?

Comment: @ZelosMalum I think prove by contradiction would easy.

Comment: Google sieve of eratosthones. But in the meantime think about this: if p|n then $\frac np | n $. Which is bigger; p or n/p?

Comment: In order for this to be true we need to exclude $n=1$.  You'll see that the proof requires the assumption that $n$ is divisible by at least one prime, which isn't true for $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is

If no prime $p$
 less than or equal to 
$\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$
then
$n$ is prime.

The contrapositive,
which is equivalent, is

If $n$ is not prime
then 
there is a prime $p$
 less than or equal to 
$\sqrt{n}$ that 
divides $n$.

This might be easier to prove.